# ground deck structure

Tags: wood, deck, structural

We are building an ipe wood deck in our patio - on the ground. The landscaper had originally said he'd use 4x6 pressure-treated pieces, long side up - so 6" high, to create at least 6" clearance above sand. He planned to space them 16" apart for the 1x6 ipe planks. He just showed up with 4x4" pieces for the structure joists, which he said he would then add a 2x6 at 90 degrees on top of the 4x4 for added stability. I worry he did this to save money on the joist pieces that were supposed to be 4x6. Does this make sense?

Our patio deck will be about 10'x20'.

Comment: I suspect that he did some research and/or thinking after your initial session and improved the design. Technically the 2x6s are the joists. I would call the 4x4s "foundation beams."

Comment: That's what he said. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with the new elevation, then it's fine. Just be sure that the ends of the 2x6s are blocked to prevent them from tipping over. See [IRC R507.6.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch05_SecR507.6.2).

The previous design would have been labor intense to get flat and you probably would have gotten a wavy surface. I prefer the new design for its higher likelihood of good quality. I guess the 2x6 span lengths are now the tricky part. By the book, 2x6 span length varies with snow load if the snow exceeds the 40 psf live load. For typical regions the 40 psf live load governs from the span table under [IRC R507.6](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch05_SecR507.6). The snow load entries were just added to the IRC in 2021. The case is so unusual that nobody thought to include them earlier.

Stud grade 2x6s is a potential cheat that an ignorant person or a swindler might substitute to save a buck. The span table that I linked is predicated on certain grades and species of lumber, where typically you would have a hard time finding an inferior grade at the corporate hardware store. 2x6s are an exception, though, where stud grade 2x6s are often stocked for building walls (not decks). If the 2x6s are incised from pressure treatment or obviously pressure treated, then they're not stud grade, and there's a very high likelihood that they meet the grade predicate of that table.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. I appreciate your comments.